# repeater inside update panel is not working

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server"> 
  <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrtest" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrtest_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptrtest_ItemDataBound"> 
      <div> <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/> <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" > </asp:Button> 
      </div> 
    </asp:Repeater> 
  </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on button click event i'm sending name to another usercontrol in same page.

i'm having repeater inside update panel this whole thing in one usercontrol  my problem when i click submit button inside repeater there is no Asynchronous post back happening please any one help.

Comment: Please paste ur code here.

Comment: Show the contents of your Repeater ItemTemplate and show your button click handler

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrtest" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrtest_ItemCommand"
        OnItemDataBound="rptrtest_ItemDataBound">
       <div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" >
                                   </asp:Button>
</div>
    </asp:Repeater>
    
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

on button click event i'm sending name to another usercontrol in same page.

Comment: How are you sending the name to the other user control?

Comment: i'm sending by using properties.

Comment: Please show your `btnSubmit_Click` function. You can edit your question to insert this information.

Answer (score 2):

Your repeater is missing the ItemTemplate tag

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server"> 
  <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrtest" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptrtest_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptrtest_ItemDataBound"> 
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div> <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/> <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" > </asp:Button> </div> 
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 
  </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**References**

- [Repeater (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)
- [Item Template (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate.aspx)